# firebase storage authentication for same project cloud function

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function that responds to firestore events. 
I want this cloud function to manipulate files on the storage of the same project.

```
const file = admin.storage().bucket().file('dataPackages/logos/pizza.png');
console.log('file exists', file.exists());
```

The project has anonymous authentication enabled, and the rules for the storage are

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      // allow read, write: if request.auth!=null;
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

For some reason I get this error

```
 ApiError: shakescratchpad@appspot.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access to shakescratchpad.appspot.com/dataPackages/logos/pizza.png
```

Comment: Have a look at this. This might be helpful. [firebase-functions-samples-issue](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/issues/299)

Comment: What you're showing is not a Cloud Function that responds to file uploads to a storage bucket.  Please look at the documentation for Cloud Storage triggers to get started.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events

Comment: What I am showing is PART of a cloud function. It actually gets triggered. The problem is the ApiError it generates.